# How is Facebook able to show a custom modal window for unsaved changes in their application?

Tags: html, reactjs, facebook, react-router

I'm interested in solutions that use React.
I've only been able to find examples that show browser-level warnings, but haven't been able to find examples for presenting a custom modal window when a user moves away from the page with unsaved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a event called `onbeforeunload` that lives on the global `windows` object.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', () => {
    //show your React modal
    this.setState({ isModalShown: true });
    if (this.state.choose) {
      return undefined;
    }
  });
 }

render() {
  return  (
    <Modal open={this.state.isModalShown}>
      <p>Do you wish to continue?</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ choose: true })}>Cancel</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ choose: false })}>Ok</button>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Be careful with browser support as not all the browsers behave the same https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

It is highly likely that facebook solution is quite advanced and uses workarounds for different browsers.

Comment: Note this won't work navigating to a different domain. i.e. from facebook.com -> linkedin.com